# Как создать файл с именем из переменной?

Tags: python, файлы, path

Помогите сделать функцию которая создает бинарный файл где:
path - путь к файлу
file_name - имя файла
Я знаю только как создать при помощи path и в конце самому указать название, например:

```
with open(path, wb) as binary_file:
    pass
```

И path будет 'C:\Projects\Test_Project\Test.bin'
А как сделать название из какой-либо переменной?

```
from pathlib import Path


def create_backup(path, file_name):
    with open(path, 'wb') as bfile_employee:
        pass


path_to_dir = Path(r'C:\Projects\Test_Project')
file_name = 'archived_file.bin'
create_backup(path_to_dir, file_name)
```

Comment: Просто в строке `with open(path, 'wb') as bfile_employee:` вместо `path` напишите `path + '\' + filename`, или можно еще проще сделать: вместо принятия двух аргументов в функции `create_backup` можно принимать только один, т. е. вместо `create_backup(path_to_dir, file_name)` написать `create_backup(path_to_dir + '\' + file_name)`

Comment: и да, не забывайте помечать ответы как правильные с помощью галочки)

Comment: @zolars `path + '\' + filename` даст ошибку - бэкслэш нужно экранировать, причём `r-строка` тут не поможет, потому что бэкслэш в конце строки, тут только экран `path + '\\' + filename`

Comment: @CrazyElf да, спасибо что подловили)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно конкатенацию сделать:

```
with open(path + '/' + file_name, 'wb') as bfile_employee:
    pass
```

Или f-строку использовать:

```
with open(f'{path}{file_name}', 'wb') as bfile_employee:
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

Библиотека `pathlib` специально предназначена для того, чтобы такие вещи делать проще - пути типа `Path` можно объединять со строками просто через оператор деления `/`. Но при этом получается линуксовый стиль обозначения каталогов, не уверен, будет ли это нормально работать в винде, нужно проверять. Но по идее должно:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def create_backup(path, file_name):
    with open(path/file_name, 'wb') as bfile_employee:
        pass

path_to_dir = Path('C:/Projects/Test_Project') # линуксовые разделители
file_name = 'archived_file.bin'
create_backup(path_to_dir, file_name)
```

Впрочем, я видимо проверял в линуксе, поэтому у меня линуксовый стиль и получился, возможно в винде можно оставить бэкслэши в пути и объединяться будет через них, нужно просто проверить, что выдаст `print(path/file_name)`. Скорее всего будет использоваться сепаратор, соответствующий системе.